# Wrong version of DLL in output directory

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, odata

Got a really annoying problem with DLLs here:

***The Error***

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Edm, Version=5.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

***My Setup***

```
Solution Root
- Common
    - Lib1
    - Lib2
    - etc..
- Plugins
    - PluginA
    - PluginB
    - etc..
- MainProject
```

Notes:

- **PluginA** and **PluginB** both reference **Lib1** AND **Lib2**.
- **Lib1**, **Lib2** and **PluginB** reference **Microsoft.Data.Edm** version 5.6.3
- **PluginA** does not reference any version of **Microsoft.Data.Edm** at all because I don't need Web API in there like I do for the other projects
- The plugins' output directories are set to `~/Plugins/<PluginName>/`
- `~/Plugins/PluginA/` has a copy of **Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll**. This is to be expected because **Lib1** and **Lib2** reference that assembly and it is copied to the output directory along with **Lib1.dll** and **Lib2.dll**. What's NOT expected is that the version is 5.6.0 instead of 5.6.3... ***this is what's causing the error...***

I have no idea where that version is coming from. This has been driving me crazy for days now. How is this even possible? Am I doing something really stupid? I have searched everywhere for a version 5.6.0 and could not find one. All projects that reference **Microsoft.Data.Edm** have 5.6.3... yet somehow a copy of 5.6.0 finds its way to the output directory for **PluginA**.
**PluginB** is obviously not affected because it directly references **Microsoft.Data.Edm** for itself. Totally confused..

Comment: You could stick in an event handler for the appdomain's AssemblyResolve method and see where this thing is coming from. Better yet, use the even handler to ignore the wrong version and force load the correct version.

Comment: @Kell, Thanks, but from my understanding, that will only tell me at runtime where the DLL is coming from.. as I said, I know it's in the output directory.. I want to know why that wrong version is in the output directory (problem during build, not runtime)

Comment: Doh! I see that now :) I have seen this kind of weirdness before and resolved it by looking at the text of the project files in notepad. In my case setting the "specific version" of the referenced assembly to true solved this. But you may want to look at how the included "hintpaths" look in the text of the csproj files.